# -bash: npm: command not found

Tags: nodejs, bash, npm, terminal

Estoy ejecutando npm desde la terminal pero no me funciona, me sale este error, alguien sabe alguna solución?, ya desinstalé y volví a instalar y sigue sin funcionar.

intenté: 
`$ brew update`
`$ brew uninstall node`
`$ brew install node`

y sigue sin funcionar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira, acabo de instalar y desinstalar otra ves node y sigue sin funcionar, intenté con `npm install npm@latest -g` y sale lo mismo `-bash: npm: command not found` @Hubert Ronald

Comment: Si, no entiendo por que no me funciona. @HubertRonald

Comment: Si, sigue como si no pasara nada `Juans-MacBook-Pro:~ juanpablo$ which npm`
`Juans-MacBook-Pro:~ juanpablo$ `

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar. @HubertRonald

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si deseas saber en que `path` está instalado `npm`  prueba con

```
which npm
```

Si no hay nada es porque no está instalado, en este caso lo puedes conseguir de acá [GET npm](https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm) también proporcionan el `node.js` que se requiere primero para instalar el `npm` pero al ver el terminal posteado, se aprecia que ya cuentas con él.

Si estas teniendo los problemas que comentas se podría instalar bajando el paquete y hacerlo manualmente de acá: https://nodejs.org/en/

Otra forma es descargar el paquete desde el `bash` usando simplemente el instalador de macOS lo he probado y me ha funcionado, porque actualizó mi version de `node.js` de la `v10.15.3 LTS` a la `v11.11.0`. En el terminal poner lo siguiente:

```
curl "https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/node-${VERSION:-$(wget -qO- https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/ | sed -nE 's|.*>node-(.*)\.pkg</a>.*|\1|p')}.pkg" > "$HOME/Downloads/node-latest.pkg" && sudo installer -store -pkg "$HOME/Downloads/node-latest.pkg" -target "/"
```

La anterior línea ha sido tomada de [Installing Node.js via package manager](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/) sección [macOS](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#macos) ahi también comentan la alternativa que has usado con **Homebrew:** `(brew install node)` y que al parecer no funciona.

Comment: Mira, acabo de instalar y desinstalar otra ves node y sigue sin funcionar, intenté con npm install npm@latest -g y sale lo mismo -bash: npm: command not found @Hubert Ronald

Comment: He incluido en la respuesta hacer la instalación del paquete `node.js` desde el `bash`

Answer (score 1):

> Habilitar el repositorio de NodeSource ejecutando el siguiente comando curl como usuario con privilegios de sudo:

~$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -

El comando agregará la clave de firma NodeSource a su sistema, creará un archivo de repositorio de fuentes de apt, instalará todos los paquetes necesarios y actualizará el caché de apt.

Si necesita instalar otra versión, por ejemplo 14.x, simplemente cambie setup_12.x por setup_14.x

->Una vez que el repositorio de NodeSource esté habilitado, instale Node.js y npm escribiendo:

~$ sudo apt install nodejs
~$ sudo apt install npm

->Verificamos que Node.js y npm se hayan instalado correctamente imprimiendo sus versiones:
node -v debemos tener la versión v12.16.3
npm -v debemos tener la versión 6.14.4

->Luego instalamos npx:
**~$ sudo npm install -g npx **

Answer (score -1):

```
brew uninstall node
brew update
brew upgrade
brew cleanup
brew install node
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local
brew link --overwrite node
brew postinstall node
```

(siguiendo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056115/how-to-install-latest-version-of-node-using-brew#14001583)

Comment: He intentando lo que has sugerido pero siento decir que `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local` congela el terminal y se cuelga... asimismo la versión del `node` en mi caso sigue siendo **10.15.3 LTS** y no **11.11.0** eso quiere decir que los comandos no han reinstalado el `node` a la versión actual, y esto sucede así porque en la pregunta se ve que al usar `brew`, el OP tiene la version **v11.11.0** de `node`

Comment: También aclaro que cuando se emplea `sudo` en terminal mac se requiere clave de administrador... que en mi caso si la tengo, así que no fue por dicho motivo que se colgó el terminal. [Using the sudo command in Terminal requires an administrator password](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202035)

Comment: Si te da problemas el paso del chown sáltalo. En el enlace que te pegué dice que al instalar a veces no hace bien el link ni el postinstall en ciertas versiones.